# Use AJAX to add an ajax link to the page - Yii

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, yii

I have a user interface I'm trying to build out for an application I'm building. My code adds an AJAX link using a Yii helper function-

```
echo CHtml::ajaxLink('Link', array('getajaxlinks'),array('update'=>'#div'));
```

My wish is for the function that the link calls to update #items div with more AJAX links. I've written the following so far-

```
    public function actionGetajaxlinks(){
        $string = CHtml::ajaxLink('Another Link', array('getlistitems'),array('update'=>'#items'),array('class'=>'btn btn-link')); 
        echo $string;
    }
```

Needless to say it's not quite working. The link is being made and fires with no javascript errors, but I believe the id of the new link is being assigned the same id as the first link and clicking is therefore firing the first event handler rather than firing the new event.

Is there a way of fixing the above code? Or is there another way of delivering this that's better thought out?

N.B: If/when I get this working, the wish is to deliver multiple links at the same time through actionGetajaxlinks

Answer (score 0):

You can use a public variable to control this like

```
<?php
     class AbcController extends Controller
      {
          public $i = 1;

          public function actionGetajaxlinks(){
               $string = CHtml::ajaxLink('Another Link', array('getlistitems'),array('update'=>'#items_'.$this->i),array('class'=>'btn btn-link')); 
           $this->i ++;
           echo $string;

          }
      }

?>
```

This will solve your problem.

Comment: Hi Neeraj,
Thanks for your answer. I don't believe this solves the problem though. It will just update a different element.